# JQuery Mobile Markup And CSS Not Rendering On Blackberry 5

Tags: jquery-mobile

My jquery mobile site is working on all blackberry 6 devices fine but no styles are showing up on blackberry 5 models. Is there anything I need to add to make jQuery mobile render on blackberry 5? I am using JQM v1.1.1, A blackberry BOLD 9700 device

Here is what I am trying to render:

Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UserMobile.master.cs" Inherits="User.Mobile.UserMobile" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="Css/jquery.mobile.custom.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Css/jquery.mobile.custom.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <%--<link href="Css/eneCustom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />--%>

  <%--  <script src="Js/jquery-1.8.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
    <script src="Js/jquery1.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



    /

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="b">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">

         <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TopHeaderContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   

 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="FooterContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->



</body>

</html>
```

Main Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Mobile/UserMobile.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DummyPAge.aspx.cs" Inherits="User.Mobile.DummyPAge" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="TopHeaderContent" runat="server">
<h1>HEADER</h1>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
HI THERE
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="FooterContent" runat="server">
<h1>FOOTER</h1>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery mobile isn't supported in RIM5. See http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/about/platforms.html for supported platforms.

Comment: it says its supported in B grade but i dont even see the css being rendered in BB 5. BB 6 the jqm works fine

Comment: What version of jquery itself are you using. Have seen issues in the past using jquery core 1.7.1 with bb5. Try using 1.6.4. If no success post your code please.

Comment: I am using a BOLD 9700 device